# Zoom Region Not Working Properly - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I was trying to get a subplot of a region from an plot that should be zoomed in.

Code: (Minimal, Reproducible one)

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

#Loading Data
data = pd.read_csv("lol.csv")
data.head()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ypoints = np.array(data['KDA'])
xpoints = np.array(data['Win/Lose'])

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset, inset_axes
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.scatter(xpoints, ypoints)
ax.set_xlabel("Win/Loss")
ax.set_ylabel("KDA")
axins = ax.inset_axes([0.3, 0.3, 0.47, 0.47])
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 0, -0.5, 6.5
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)

ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins, edgecolor="black")
```

It is showing this:

[image: Problem]

It should show somewhat like this:

[image: Probable Solution]

or somewhat like this: [(Collected)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-zoom-inset-axes-py)

[image: Probable Solution 2]

What should I do now?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to actually draw the scatter plot in the new axes: `axins.scatter(xpoints, ypoints)`

Comment: It did work. Naive me. @DavidG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I just forgot to adding the scatter function.

`axins.scatter(xpoints, ypoints)`